# How to create a Lichtenberg Figure?

Tags: graphics3d, generative-art, fractals

I want to create a simulated Lichtenberg figure in a manner similar to this image:

What is a good method to generate Lichtenberg figures?

[image]

There is a very helpful post on Wolfram Community about [Lichtenberg figures](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1065956).
There is also a helpful example of using Python to simulate Lichtenberg figures available on [GitHub](https://github.com/chromia/lichtenberg). This [example](https://github.com/chromia/lichtenberg/blob/master/docs/basic.md) includes that can be translated into the Wolfram language.

Comment: I changed it from [tag:graphics] to [tag:graphics3d] because that's what the figure shows. If that seems wrong, please edit your question to clarify just what you want. Your answer below does not answer the question, unless the figures shown on Community are exactly what you want. The answer seems more along the lines of a comment that should be edited into the question above. If the post on Community is what you want, then please edit the answer to include working code. Answers depending on external links are discouraged.

Comment: I will update my question and answer.

Comment: Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I wonder if some form of `CellularAutomaton[]` could be used